# Portfolio tracker like PersonalCapital.com with history

Tags: finance

I am looking for a portfolio tracker which can link to my brokerage account and download transactions including all available historical transactions.

- I looked at MorningStar, unfortunately, I could not figure out if it could link to the my existing brokerage accounts.
- PersonalCapital.com was perfect.  Unfortunately, it starts tracking the portfolio only from the day you start the membership, even though it has all the past information to analyze the portfolio.

Is there any other site/software which can do both, downloading past available data and show the past performance?

Comment: "I could not figure out if it could link to my existing brokerage accounts" Did you ask them?

Comment: Yes, I got the response from MorningStar today, the import of transactions is completely manual.